# lapply strings to subset via brackets[]

Tags: r

There is almost certainly an easier way to go about this, but perhaps I've just been awake too long. I want to use the following vector of strings:

```
lap_list <- paste0(seq(1,length(mpg[[1]]),10), ":", seq(10,length(mpg[[1]]),10))
```

and use the vector to subset such as `mpg[lap_list[1], ]`. Alternatively, I could use dplyr for something with slice:

```
mpg %>%
    slice(lap_list[1])
```

Both methods are giving the same error, and beyond parse(eval()) or as.numeric() I'm having a hard time wording my question for google.

The ultimate goal is to have a function such that I could lapply the graph outputs. Say:

```
barchart <- function(data_slice) {
    mpg %>%
        slice(data_slice) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x=model)) + geom_bar()
    }

lapply(lap_list, barchart)
```

Comment: sorry, i'm not clear what your inputs are or what your desired output is. what is `mpg`?

Comment: The code doesn't look right, I think you're missing a `c` or maybe a `seq` in there somewhere - `paste0(seq(1,length(mpg[[1]]),10), ":", seq(10,length(mpg[[1]]),10))` maybe?

Comment: @MichaelChirico `mpg` is dataset in `ggplot2` (`ggplot2::mpg`)

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for catching that. I got the second seq() in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste the sequence of rows you want to subset using `paste0`, you don't have much option then to use `eval(parse))` in some way or the other.

An alternative is to create a sequence of rows that you want to subset and store it in vectors. Pass them in `Map` to `slice` from the data and then plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

n <- nrow(mpg)
start <- seq(1,n,10) 
#Added an extra `n` here to make the length of start and end equal
end <- c(seq(10,n,10), n)

barchart <- function(data, start, end) {
  data %>%
    slice(start:end) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=model)) + geom_bar()
}
list_of_plots <- Map(barchart, start, end, MoreArgs = list(data = mpg))
```

You can access each individual plots using `list_of_plots[[1]]`, `list_of_plots[[2]]` etc.

---

Perhaps, you can also create groups of 10 rows and store the plots in the dataframe :

```
mpg %>% 
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/10)) %>% 
  summarise(plot = list(ggplot(cur_data(), aes(x=model)) + geom_bar()))
```

Comment: Quick question from someone who doesn't know the first thing about *ggplot2* - you can't `group_by` and `ggplot` ?

Comment: You can. I just tried this and it gives the same output. `mpg %>% group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/10)) %>% summarise(plot = list(ggplot(cur_data_all(), aes(x=model)) + geom_bar()))` where `cur_data_all()` is current data of the group.